# How to pass multiple route parameters in Ionic-Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, angular-routerlink

I am able to get a single param through route like `page1/id1` in Ionic 5.
If I want to get multiple parameters for a module, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **app-routing.module.ts**, modify the path to-

```
{
path: 'page1/:id1/:id2',
loadChildren: () => import('./pages/page1/page1.module').then(m => m.Page1PageModule)
},
```

In the page through which you want to access this page, say for instance *page0.page.html* include-

```
<ion-item button [routerLink]="['/', 'page1', id1,id2]" >Go to Page1 </ion-item>
```

In *page1.page.ts* , in order to access these params, inclde the following in ngOnInit -

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

..
constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private router : Router){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let id1 = params.get('id1');
      let id2 = params.get('id2');
   });
}
```